# (Winforms) GridView too large for display area, can't remove any columns.

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

**The Source of the Problem**

I have a situation where an old WinForms grid was placed in a `PageView`, then generates another page and sets it active if you click one of the rows.  The original idea was that the second `PageViewPage`'s grid would contain "detail information" and that the original grid would bear a summary, but over the years more and more data from the detail page has been added to the original grid.  This turned a 6-column `GridView` that needed to be stretched to fit the screen into a 20-column `GridView` that causes a lot of scrolling to happen, especially in our manufacturing plants where some of the oldest machines still have 1024 x 768 CRT's.

**The Problem**

I'm developing on this screen, now using Telerik controls. My task is to find a way to display all of the data from *both* pages in the one grid, but with little-to-no horizontal scrolling required.  After appending the few fields which were not already duplicated and combining related data (i.e. Account Number and Account Name being one hyphenated column with word wrap instead of two), I've got 19 columns. 1/3rd of the grid is still offscreen.

SO far I have:

- Combined like data (as above)
- Reduced font sizes slightly
- Changed the `BestFitColumnsMode` to `DisplayedCells`
- Reduced all columns which had a fixed number of characters to display to the right size to display only those characters
- Abbreviated column names that are larger than their potential data and replaced with a symbolic icon on `CheckBoxColumns`
- Replace all written-out "`true`" - "`false`" `TextBoxColumns` with `CheckBoxColumns`

Now I'm stuck.  I considered dropping the column headers and instead making a bunch of `RadGridView` pairs for each line, effectively "wrapping" the grid, but that would rob me of the sorting and grouping features we actually need which are provided by Telerik out of the box.  Is there a "best practice" for situations like this, or perhaps a feature of `GridView` or `RadGridView` I'm missing?

One option has already been ruled out; I can't replace this with a list of `UserControl` that contains labels (i.e. "ID: xx" instead of an ID column with xx in a cell) or similar.  Column headers are required by the project.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the UI?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.  Partially because of the employer, partially because the grid contains sensitive information so I'd have to black out most of what we'd learn from the screenshot, and partially because even at 1920x1080 one third of the grid is offscreen so to fit here would make it abysmally tiny and hard to see.   What I can say is that all cells contain data unique to that line alone, so there are no redundant columns or row cells.

Comment: I think I'll fix this by using a CollapsiblePanel.   That's opening a new can of worms though.